# How can I unhighlight everything highlighted by `highlight-regexp`?

Tags: highlighting

If I do this:

```
M-x highlight-regexp \cite{\(.+\)}
```

then pick a color. Later, if want to unhiglight all previous higlights, I have to do them one by one, e.g.

```
M-x unhighlight-regexp \cite{\(.+\)}
```

Is there not a command to un-highlight all?

Comment: The docs for `unhighlight-regexp` suggest using `C-u` and then `M-x unhighlight-regexp` to remove all of them.

Comment: @amitp: Please consider providing that info as an answer. Comments can be deleted at any time. Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs for `unhighlight-regexp` suggest using `C-u and then M-x unhighlight-regexp` to remove all of them. (credits: @amitp)